# How to remove empty space between items in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a column which has 2 items (a custom drawer and a container).
Both items have the same color (widget.color).
There is a white line of around 1 pixel between both parts.

The widget is built in a for loop 3 times for 3 different colors, so you can see the white 3 times.

Is there any way in flutter to remove this spacing between Column items?

[image: empty white line between 2 items in column]

[image: code of each item]

Comment: it will be easy for us if you can share your HeaderPainter

Answer (score 1):

I think you are giving some padding/margin to the items in the column and that's why it shows some space between them just remove padding/margin from the items.
in a Column, children have not by default space between them.
In your design, I guess your custom paint contains some size/space at the top, which is showing space between items in a for loop.